# Keep attrib changes after refresh

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe that contains this

```
<iframe id="youtube" width="284" height="179" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/somevideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and i want to change the src, using this

```
$("#videos").click(function () {
var url = prompt("new url video");

$("#youtube").attr("src", url);
```

But when i refresh the page, it loads the first url(somevideo), my question is, is there a way(without accesing a db) to keep the new url?

Comment: Cookies or localstorage?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can use this plugin to save the url in local storage with cookie fallbacks: https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: thanks a lot , i was kinda lost